# Why do $\psi, \psi^*$ and the potential energy operator commute here?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, commutator

This is the one-dimensional time-dependent Schrodinger Equation:
$$i\hbar \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}= -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2 \psi }{\partial x^2} +\displaystyle {\hat {V}\psi}$$<br
My textbook takes the complex conjugate of this equation(note that $\psi^*$ is the conjugate of $\psi$),
$$-i\hbar \frac{\partial \psi ^*}{\partial t}= -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2 \psi ^* }{\partial x^2} +\displaystyle {\hat {V}\psi^*}$$
and multiplies it by $\psi$
$$-i\hbar\psi \frac{\partial \psi ^*}{\partial t}= -\frac{\hbar^2\psi}{2m}\frac{\partial^2 \psi ^* }{\partial x^2} +\displaystyle {\hat {V}|\psi|^2}$$
**My Question:**
How can $\psi \displaystyle {\hat {V}\psi^*}= \displaystyle {\hat {V}|\psi|^2}?$Does it not depend on the nature of $\displaystyle {\hat {V}}?$
For example, if $\displaystyle {\hat {V}}$ was $-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, given that $\psi = e^{i(kx-\omega t)}$($k$ and $\omega$ are constants),
$\psi \displaystyle {\hat {V}\psi^*}=-e^{i(kx-\omega t)} i \hbar(ik e^{-i(kx-\omega t)})=\hbar k$ whereas
$\displaystyle {\hat {V}|\psi|^2} = \displaystyle {\hat {V}1}=0!$
Or is $\displaystyle {\hat {V}|\psi|^2}$ just a notation?

**Note: I know the $V$ I've chosen is the momentum operator; I'm only trying to show that the $\psi, \psi^*$ and an operator do not necessarily commute that way.**
What's wrong with my understanding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conventionally, $V$ is used to denote the *potential*, and is a function only of position and not momentum. This follows the usage in classical mechanics, where the potential is a function of position only. You are right that if $V$ was a generic operator that could depend on momentum, then you would need to be more careful.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But how can I be sure that the three will commute? Is there a proof for it?

Comment: @AmbicaGovind In the position basis, $\hat{x}$ is just an ordinary number. The same goes for any function of $x$, such as the potential. Since multiplication of ordinary numbers is commutative, you don't need to be careful about ordering.

Comment: @AmbicaGovind multiplication of complex function and complex conjugate is squared of that. $$\psi\psi^*=|\psi|^2$$ that's identity in complex analysis. If you multiply both side by $\phi$ the identity doesn’t change (taken $\phi$ as just example)